# Google share link to sheet with options

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to add code to the share link that google gives you to automatically update a query?

Let us say the link is "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/mysheet/edit?usp=sharing"

Is there code I can add to the end of this link to update the where in my query on this sheet?

Comment: Do you mean a link to a specific cell? If so see [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44473/link-to-a-cell-in-a-google-sheets-via-url)

Comment: I mean to update the where part of the query function.